# Make Windows "open" everything by passing it to my program

Tags: windows

I'm writing my own anti-virus for a school project. I have basics nailed down like checking the MD5 hash of a file against a library of known bad hashes, checking the file for known bad pattern of bytes, checking if it'll try to connect to the net... At the moment this all works by passing the path of the file to check as argument to my program.

What I would like to do is something more similar to the way real anti-virus/malware works that is by checking every file the user double clicks on.

IE: When double-clicking on TEST.exe in explorer, instead of directly launching TEST.exe I would like the OS to actually call ANTIVIRUS.exe with the path to TEST.exe. ANTIVIRUS.exe will then check TEST.exe and determine if it's safe to launch or not.

I thought about modifying the "Open With" properties in the registry, but I noticed you can't set which program to open an executable with.

How can I change Windows (XP,7,8) settings to do something like this (if it's possible?). If it can't be done this way how do other anti-virus' manage to check files as they're being launched?

(NOTE: Originally posted this on superuser.com but was told to try it here as it may require "Win32 API Hooking?". I'm writing my anti-virus in Python but I'm fluent in C# as well if needed.)

Comment: API hooking is a goal that's rather incompatible with most students' desire to graduate in four years or less.  You certainly can specify the EXE to use, there would be no "with" otherwise.  Add a registry key to HKCU/exefile/shell, give it a subkey named command whose default value is your program with %1 to pass the file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make Windows "open" everything by passing it to my program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22455369/make-windows-open-everything-by-passing-it-to-my-program)