# Make Windows "open" everything by passing it to my program

Tags: windows

I'm writing my own anti-virus for a school project. I have basics nailed down like checking the MD5 hash of a file against a library of known bad hashes, checking the file for known bad pattern of bytes, checking if it'll try to connect to the net... At the moment this all works by passing the path of the file to check as argument to my program.

What I would like to do is something more similar to the way real anti-virus/malware works that is by checking every file the user double clicks on.

IE: When double-clicking on TEST.exe in explorer, instead of directly launching TEST.exe I would like the OS to actually call ANTIVIRUS.exe with the path to TEST.exe. ANTIVIRUS.exe will then check TEST.exe and determine if it's safe to launch or not.

I thought about modifying the "Open With" properties in the registry, but I noticed you can't set which program to open an executable with.

How can I change Windows (XP,7,8) settings to do something like this (if it's possible?). If it can't be done this way how do other anti-virus' manage to check files as they're being launched?

Comment: What program is this written in?

Comment: also possibly helpful: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43586/File-System-Filter-Driver-Tutorial

Answer (score 1):

What you call "Open" is really `ShellExecute`. That's not what real AV uses, as `ShellExecute` eventually calls `CreateProcess`. But there are more ways to call `CreateProcess`, perhaps most importantly it can be called directly.

@wmz has another reasonable (but complex) hint: you can check at file system driver level. This isn't a regular program but runs as part of the kernel. That makes it a lot harder to program, for instance all .Net languages are unusable.